# Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last) I can't make the multi threading work

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to build a discord bot who does 2 things in the same time.
The first fonction check some profils on twitter and retweets when those profils tweet.
The second take a screenshot on an headless chrome with selenium every 5 minutes and shares it on a different channel.

It seems that the 2 threads refuse to work at the same time. And when I time.sleep, the second thread stops working.

It's important to note that if there isn't any new tweet, the second thread simply doesn't work.

Here is the full code:

main.py :

```
import influenceur  #See bellow
import threading
import long_short #See bellow
import discord

# Connexion discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

    th1 = threading.Thread(target=client.loop.create_task(influenceur.influenceur(client)))
    th2 = threading.Thread(target=client.loop.create_task(long_short.long_short(client)))

    th1.start()
    th2.start()

    th1.join()
    th2.join()

client.run(<tocken>)
```

influenceur.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import tweepy
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from PIL import Image
import asyncio
import data
import data

# Read txt, return int list
def read_txt(txt):
    with open(txt, "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        liste = f.read().split("\n")
        list_id = []
        del liste[-1]
        for item in liste:
            item_int = int(item)
            list_id.append(item_int)

    return list_id

# Write in txt
def write_txt(tweet_id, txt):
    with open(txt, "a", encoding="utf8") as f:
        f.write(str(tweet_id) + "\n")
    print("id enregistrée")

async def influenceur(client):
    # Connexion twitter
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(<key>, <key_secret>)
    auth.set_access_token(<access_tocken>, <access_tocken_secret>)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    usernames_influenceur = ["elonmusk", "michael_saylor", "PeterSchiff" ,"jack", "VitalikButerin", "WarrenBuffett", "cz_binance"]
    usernames_twitos_fr = ["CryptoMatrix2", "PowerHasheur", "cryptoastblog", "cryptonews_FR", "CryptoActuFr", "maxime__prigent"]
    usernames_twitos_eng = ["TheMoonCarl", "MMCrypto", "Davincij15", "aantonop", "justinsuntron", "CryptoCobain", "BTC_Archive"]
    usernames = usernames_twitos_fr + usernames_twitos_eng + usernames_influenceur

    while True:
        try:
            for username in usernames:
                count = 2
                time.sleep(2)
                try:
                    # Get tweets
                    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username, exclude_replies=True).items(count)
                except Exception as e:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print("Error, retry : ", e)
                    pass
                print("lecture des tweets de ", username)
                for tweet in tweets:
                    id_tweet = read_txt("id_tweet.txt")
                    if tweet.id in id_tweet:
                        pass
                    else:
                        print("printing")
                        if username in usernames_influenceur:
                            channel = client.get_channel(data.influenceur_chan)
                            await channel.send("https://twitter.com/" + username + "/status/" + str(tweet.id))
                        elif username in usernames_twitos_fr:
                            channel = client.get_channel(data.twitos_fr_chan)
                            await channel.send("https://twitter.com/" + username + "/status/" + str(tweet.id))
                        elif username in usernames_twitos_eng:
                            channel = client.get_channel(data.twitos_eng_chan)
                            await channel.send("https://twitter.com/" + username + "/status/" + str(tweet.id))
                        write_txt(tweet.id, "id_tweet.txt")
            print("End of infuenceurs, sleep 5")
            time.sleep(5)
    
        except Exception as e:
            print("Erreur:", e)
            continue
```

long_short.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from PIL import Image
import discord
import asyncio
import data


async def long_short(client):
    while True:
        print("long short")
        WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,2160"

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
        chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://fr.coinalyze.net/bitcoin/usdt/binance/btcusdt_perp/price-chart-live/")

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='login']").click()

        time.sleep(3)
        email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']").send_keys(<mail>)
        password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='pwd']").send_keys(<password>)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Se connecter']").click()
        time.sleep(8)

        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
        time.sleep(1)

        driver.quit()
        ##############################

        screen = Image.open("screenshot.png")
        width, height = screen.size

        left = 83
        top = 150
        width = 1385
        height = 1960
        box = (left, top, left+width, top+height)

        area = screen.crop(box)

        area.save("screen_sized.png", "PNG")

        ###################################

        print("I'm ready.")
        channel = client.get_channel(data.long_short_chan)
        print("Channel :", channel)
        await channel.send(file=discord.File("screen_sized.png"))
        print("Screen uploadé, wait 60")
    
        time.sleep(420)
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception in thread Thread-3:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run        
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: '_asyncio.Task' object is not callable
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run        
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: '_asyncio.Task' object is not callable
```

Comment: Why are you using asynchronous within a blocking function? If you want it to run in a separate thread it cannot be a coroutine, please either use non-blocking asynchronous code and run it as a coroutine or use normal synchronous code and run it in a separate thread, mixing both is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: I'm using asynchronous code because this is what is adviced in the doc for discord.py. I just tried without, the code run, but it never sends the message to discord.

And I'm recieving this error : c:\Users\louis\Documents\prog\discord\eyespy\influenceur.py:69: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  channel.send("https://twitter.com/" + username + "/status/" + str(tweet.id))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation tracebacK

On the main.py code, I just noticed on VSCode that the code after variable th2 is unreachable.

Comment: Alright, well check out my answer, it may be confusing if you don't know the a bit of `asyncio`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to run a "blocking" coroutine in a separate thread:

```py
import asyncio
import contextlib

async def run_non_trapping_coro(func, /, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper():
        with contextlib.closing(fn(*args, **kwargs).__await__()) as gen:
            try:
                value = gen.send(None)
            except StopIteration as exc:
                return exc.value
            else:
                raise Exception(f"Unexpected yield {value} from {func}")
    return await asyncio.to_thread(wrapper)
```

If you’re using python <3.9

```py
import asyncio
import contextlib

async def run_non_trapping_coro(func, /, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    def wrapper():
        with contextlib.closing(fn(*args, **kwargs).__await__()) as gen:
            try:
                value = gen.send(None)
            except StopIteration as exc:
                return exc.value
            else:
                raise Exception(f"Unexpected yield {value} from {func}")
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, wrapper)
```

Usage:

```py
await run_non_trapping_coro(influenceur.influenceur(client))
```

You can run it as a task to exit out of the function or use `asyncio.gather` to wait for the results

```py
# Tasks
client.loop.create_task(run_non_trapping_coro(influenceur.influenceur, client.loop))
client.loop.create_task(run_non_trapping_coro(long_short.long_short, client.loop))

# asyncio.gather
await asyncio.gather(
    run_non_trapping_coro(influenceur.influenceur, client.loop)
    run_non_trapping_coro(long_short.long_short, client.loop)
)
```